# simplify formula using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

Hi i'm trying to do the following:-

```
pvliab <- array(0,c(num_samples,num_time_periods,num_groups))
Ben <- array(0,c(num_samples,num_time_periods,num_groups))

v <- 0.04

pvliab[,1,] <- Ben[,1,]*v
pvliab[,2,] <- Ben[,1,]*v + Ben[,2,]*(v^2)
pvliab[,3,] <- Ben[,1,]*v + Ben[,2,]*(v^2) + Ben[,3,]*(v^3)
pvliab[,4,] <- Ben[,1,]*v + Ben[,2,]*(v^2) + Ben[,3,]*(v^3) + Ben[,4,]*(v^4)
```

and so on

How do i simplify it using 'for'?

Comment: Who's Ben? Do we know him?

Comment: Maybe a fan of Ben Bolker :)

Comment: Maybe it isn't obvious. @csgillespie is asking for [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059). E.g., you could edit the output of `dput(Ben)` into your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to produce a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `Ben[,3,]*(v^3)`?

Comment: All the same, now that we've had our fun initiating this guy, someone give him the (trivial) `for` loop, eh?  `for(j in 1:4) output[j]<-sum(sapply(1:j,input[j]*v^j))`

Comment: yes. what's the best way to simplify the formula @Roland ? and thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

Slow nested loop implementation, but this can be vectorized and sped up consierably if you define a max for j (the index in `pvliab[,i,]`.

```
for (i in 1:n){
    c = 0
    for (j in 1:i){
        c = c + Ben[,j,]*(v^j)
    }
pvliab[,i,] <- c
}
```